# Good way to obtain all the 'Cooperative' achievements (Patch 1.4.1)

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I'm looking for a guide to obtain all the cooperative achievements in SC2.
The whole process is extremely time-consuming and it would be nice to do that in an optimized and quick way. There are many achievements making it very troublesome, for example:

- Win 250 Cooperative games against Insane A.I. opponents.
- Win 250 Cooperative games as Random against Medium A.I. opponents.
- Win 15 2v2 Cooperative games in a row against Insane A.I. opponents.
- Win 15 3v3 Cooperative games in a row against Insane A.I. opponents.

I have lots of questions about that task and I would really appreciate any advice you may have.

Knowing that 'Random against Medium' is required, is it good to play as Random against Insane as well? On the other hand, winning 15 games in a row may be difficult, so maybe it would be better to stick with Protoss and cannon rush? Are there any reliable strategies for Randoms for that particular achievements? Please share your experience!

Comment: If you can beat them on insane then it counts towards the medium achievements as well. So if you are able to do it all on insane, then you will spend less time overall. As far as strategies, I haven't done it myself so I can't help you out there.

Comment: Does the games need to have balanced teams?  Maybe you could just 7v1 an insane computer.  :)

Comment: @Jeff Short: No! For Co-op game mode you can only fight 2v2 or 3v3. You can search a match alone and are matched with other people searching or form arranged team up to 3 people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting all of the Co-op achievements turns into a pretty boring grindfest once you know how go do it.

To get all achievement in fewest games as possible you should play as Random vs. Insane AI, because - like Sorean mentioned - it counts for lower AIs. Also try to do the `each race combination vs. 3 Insane AI` and `15 Win-streak vs. 3 Insane AI` first, because after that you only need to play vs. 2 AI where the games end quicker.

Beating Insane is not hard if you use basic rush strategies for each race:

**Zerg**

- 6 Pool
- 10 Pool + Gas with Speedlings
- Inbase Spinecralwer if up against at least 1 Zerg
- skip Zerglings and go for Mutalisks from 2 Bases - this is only safe if your allies distract all enemies so they do not overwhelm you before Mutas are out

**Protoss**

- Cannon-Rush with 1st Pylon and Forge as Proxy
- transition into mass Proxygate Zealots if up against Zerg (creep is so annoying for cannonrushing)
- for very long games maybe get Void Rays

**Terran**

- 3 proxy Barracks with mass Reaper - fastest for killing worker and buildings - consider to get +1 Attack for more efficency in later game stages (if it occurs)
- Proxy Barracks and mass Marines - get some bunkers too if you don't have uber micro (so get them almost always)

Also make sure to distract the AI with a Extractor/Pylon/Engeneering Bay in his base. This way the computer will pull workers from mining and try to kill your building. Make sure they lose as much mining time as possible and have less stuff to hold your rush off. When your units come out, go for their harvesters first if its possible, but do not sacrifice too much of your army.

Obviously getting some friends in to have a relying team will make the win-streak much easier than getting random people that might fail and deny your achievement after 14 successful games.

Comment: Is it a good idea to play with friends if all of them are bronze? Maybe I should find more experienced people instead?

Comment: I think as long as they understand and can pull off one of those builds you should be fine. Cannon rush should be the easiest as it requires far less micro than Reaper or Zerglings.